# Could not insert elements into Binary Search Tree in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,key):
      self.left=None
      self.right=None
      self.val=key
def insert(root,key):
     if root is None:
        root=Node(key)
     else:
        if root.val < key:
            insert(root.right, key)
     else:
            insert(root.left, key)

     def inorder(root):
            if root:
                inorder(root.right)
                print root.val
                inorder(root.left)
     root=None
     d=input()
     while(d!=-1):
        insert(root,d)
        d=input()
     inorder(root)
```

I could not print the above tree elements with inorder.....what is wrong with the code....can anyone explain?

Comment: you never return or otherwise use the new node you create...

Comment: Also, indent your code properly. There is a whole chunk at the bottom that I am pretty sure is not part of your function. In fact, the whole thing is a giant SyntaxError waiting to happen.

Comment: New node created is inserted in insert function

Comment: And what happens to it? The reference is discarded almost immediately. It's like you never created it. When you fix your question to be minimally presentable, I will help you fix the issue. What you have now is not valid Python code at all.

Comment: @Himanshu. Please do not fix indentation errors in Python code in the future. Feel free to do so in languages like C, C++ and Java though. Whitespace is very much a part of Python syntax and you never know if OP's problem is caused by faulty indentation or another error. Let OP fix it.